# What is inversion of control, and when should I use it?

Tags: design, design-patterns, inversion-of-control

I am designing a new system and I want to know what inversion of control (IOC) is,  and more importantly, when to use it.

Does it have to be implemented with interfaces or can be done with classes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058/what-is-inversion-of-control

Answer (score 66, accepted):

**IoC** (see [Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) on Wikipedia) is applicable in cases where a component can not perform a task entirely because it doesn't have some necessary information or functionality.

The simplest example of an **IoC** pattern would be callback functions in C. For example you can declare the function:

```
void Iterator(void *list, Func* f)
```

Which iterates over `list` applying the `f` function to each of it's item. The `Iterator` function doesn't  know how each item will be processed, you just provide a function as an argument, and it processes them.

As the previous example shows, **IoC** allows you to decouple your program into separate components that don't know about each other. One of the most common versions of **IoC** is **[Dependecy Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)**.

In **Dependency Injection** each component must declare a list of dependencies required to perform it's task. At runtime a special component (generally) called an **IoC Container** performs binding between these components. It tries to provide values for published component dependencies.

Here is an example in pseudo-code:

```
class Foo 
{ 
   <Require Boo>Constructor(Boo boo){ boo.DoSomething } 
}
```

In this example class `Foo` has a constructor that requires argument of type `Boo` to perform some action.

You could create an instance of class `Foo` using code similar to this:

```
MyContainer.Create(typeof Foo)
```

`MyContainer` - is an **IoC Container**, which takes care of getting instance of `Boo` and passing it to the `Foo` constructor.

In summary, *IoC* allows you to decouple your program into separate parts. This is good because:

- Components can be easily tested independently.
- Program complexity can be reduced.
- You can switch components to another implementation.

However in some cases, **IoC** can make code harder to understand.

If you want to see good example of real-world usage of **IoC**, have a look at Mircosoft [Composite UI Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480450.aspx) and [CompositeWPF](http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPF)

I hope my explanation helps you.

Regards,
aku

Comment: Five years later, but still....That was an excellent description.  Thanks.

Comment: Not so much mentioned anywhere about IoC is the fact that code becomes harder to read. Readability is the number one priority if you want write great software. It even beats Testability. You can decouple code well beyond its usefulness.

Comment: So, a code which uses Interface based solution for all its dependencies is also based on IoC design?

Answer (score 19):

Since I dug into this myself recently, and kept all the bookmarks, the following I found invaluable for learning about IOC/DI.

[Martin Fowlers Original Article on IOC/DI](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html)

[Some Concepts To Know First](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2008/06/29/some-concepts-to-know-first.aspx)

[An excellent collection of IOC/DI Tutorials](http://wiki.bittercoder.com/Default.aspx?Page=ContainerTutorials)

[Book on IOC/DI From Manning Press](http://www.manning.com/prasanna/prasanna_meapch1.pdf)

[Source and Explanation of how to create your own IOC](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/LinFuPart4.aspx) - Cause reading source code is always the best way to understand a concept.

Answer (score 5):

Basically IoC/DI will allow you to define which implementation you're using once, and keep a static copy of your container to reference each time you want to reference it.

The Wikipedia will probably help you, but I wanted to reference your second part - yes, dependency injection can be done for classes (ie, every time this class type needs to be passed to a method, use this class), but it's better to use interfaces, because that way you can change which version of a provider, repository, etc you're using just by re-referencing it in your setup.

E.g. say you had an interface to read a stream in, and you had an XMLStreamReader and a SQLStreamReader implementation.  Then you can pass the reference to the interface to your methods and then in your IoC container tell it which one to use.

So, you could have public List ReadPeople(IStreamReader reader) and in your setup for your IoC container tell it, every time you expect an IStreamReader use SQLStreamReader.

Then if you change your mind later, you only need to change it in the one place (the setup of your container) and it won't matter how many methods ask for an IStreamReader, it will always get the default you told your container to serve up.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have a validator for checking whether or not a business is valid in your system.  Your "BusinessValidator" may have a field of type AddressValidator which validates the address part of the business.  If you want to test the BusinessValidator without executing outside code (i.e. the addressValidator code) then if you have used some sort of IoC/DI in your framework you can easliy "inject" a mock addressValidator in it's place and not have to worry about testing code outside the scope of the class under test.

Answer (score 0):

I think Inversion of Control(IoC) design principle has nothing to do with Dependency Injection(DI).
You can use DI in your project and still violate IoC principle.

Inversion of Control is all about "control flow" during runtime and during design time(source code).

Take two projects for instance, project `Business` and project `Email` where project `Business` calling some method(say `SendEmail`) in project `Email`.

During runtime flow of control goes from Business project to Email project, because Business project calling/depend/knows method from Email project.

During design or compile time flow of control goes in same direction, because in the source code we need to tell Business project what project we need to import to call `SemdEmail` method.

```
using Email; // dependency on Email project

namespace Business
{
    public class Order
    {
        private readonly Email _email;
        public Order(Email email) // dependency on Email project
        {
            _email = email;
        }

        public static void CreateOrder(Guid customerId)
        {
             // ...
             _email.SendEmail(message);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Flow of control goes in same direction during compile and runtime]

Why this is an issue?
Because now every time we make internal changes to the Email project we need to recompile all other projects which using it.

Inversion of Control principle suggests to change direction of control during compile time.
By making low level project (Email) depend on "higher" level project (Business). Then we can freely do internal changes into Email project without recompiling it's consumers.

To implement it we need to introduce an abstraction in Business project which Email project can implement.

```
namespace Business
{
    public interface IEmail
    {
        void SendEmail(string messsag);
    }

    public class Order
    {
        private readonly IEmail _email;
        public Order(IEmail email)
        {
            _email = email;
        }

        public static void CreateOrder(Guid customerId)
        {
             // ...
             _email.SendEmail(message);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Flow of control goes in opposite directions during compile and runtime]

Every application has an entry point (`main` method), this is the place where we "glue" Business project with actual implementations.